# Sometimes my jquery ajax call just hangs

Tags: jquery

I've got my users entering an email address and doing some validation as they type. It check to see if the email is in the db, and returns stuff depending on the result. Problem is, 1 out of 10 times it just sits there and never makes it to a success so my user is stuck looking at a loading animation.

Code looks like this:

```
function check_email(email) {

  var event_id = $('input[name=event_id]').val();


  // submit the data to the booking form again
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'check_booking_email.php',
    cache: false,
    data: 'booking_email='+email+'&event_id='+event_id+'',
    success: function(data) {
      $('#next').remove();
      $('.booking_email_helper').after(data);
    }
  });

 }



$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#booking_email").keyup(function() {

  var e_long = $('#booking_email').val().length;

  if(e_long > 5) {

    $('#checking_email .email_loader').fadeIn();
    $('#checking_email .text').html ('<span class="black">We are just checking your email.</span>');


    // show checking email animator...
    $('#checking_email').fadeIn();


    clearTimeout($.data(this, "timer"));
    var ms = 1000; //milliseconds
    var val = this.value;
    var wait = setTimeout(function() {
      check_email(val);
    }, ms);
    $.data(this, "timer", wait);

  } // end if e_long

   });
```

Basically, on keyup, if the character length is longer than 5, load up the animation and start the ajax call...

I'm wondering if there is something that stands out for you in my code which could be causing this issue of it just getting caught... is there a way that if for some reason it gets hung we can tell it to try again or something? I haven't played much with the fail result... I'm wondering if it is common practice to do something like call the function inside of itself if there is a fail.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not seem to be hiding the loading indicator at any point (maybe you just forgot to include it in the Q?). Try fading out #checking_email in the `$.ajax` call's success callback:

```
success: function(data) {
      $('#next').remove();
      $('.booking_email_helper').after(data);
      $("#checking_email").fadeOut();
}
```